# WP7 beta testing with ads

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads, beta-testing

I know this question isn't strictly programming related, however I have been unable to find an answer elsewhere and I'm sure the answer would benefit others.

I'm releasing a beta version of my WP7 game soon and in order to test all the functionality, I'd like to enable my pubcenter ads. Is this allowed and could you back this up with a link please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't see why not, after all, you should test the app fully, with the ads!

The [Windows Phone Beta Marketplace rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334585%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) don't state anything about not being able to enable the pubcenter ads, so I guess it is allowed!

The real question should be if the beta marketplace place allows for pubcenter ads, but if pubcenter ads can be used in beta versions of apps...